# Make regex compatible on both windows and linux

Tags: java, regex, linux, windows

I have below regex:
`".*(?=\\b)"+ Pattern.quote(key)+ "(?<=\\b).*"`
This regex is working fine on windows but not on Linux. 
How can i make this regex work on both windows and Linux

The whole code is

```
    List<String> mapKeyList = new ArrayList<String>(myPropMapKeys.keySet());
    List<String> matchFileList = new ArrayList<>();

    Predicate<String> p = (str) -> mapKeyList.stream().anyMatch(key -> str.matches(".*\\b" + Pattern.quote(key) + "\\b.*")); //To make this regex work on linux

    if (listOfIncludedFiles.length > 0) {
        System.out.println("Files that contains key are:: ");
        for (String myFile : listOfIncludedFiles) {
            File in = new File(myFile);
            InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(in));
            String mycharset = r.getEncoding();
            Charset toBePassedCharset = Charset.forName(mycharset);
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(myFile), toBePassedCharset)) {
                // try (Stream<String> stream =
                // Files.lines(Paths.get(myFile))) {
                boolean foundAKey = stream.anyMatch(p);
                if (foundAKey) {
                    matchFileList.add(myFile);

                    // Listing the files that have match
                    System.out.println("**" + ROOT_PATH + File.separator + myFile);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Number of files with matches:: " + matchFileList.size());
    }
```

The regex at `Predicate<String> p = (str) -> mapKeyList.stream().anyMatch(key -> str.matches(".*(?=\b)" + Pattern.quote(key) + "(?<=\b).*"));` is not working on linux.

my sample string is '{{LOGGER}}'

Comment: This expression is working for [[Hello]] [Hello] (Hello) ((Hello)). if my key is [Hello] and i find [[Hello]] in my current file it is still not failing.

Answer (score 0):

> i am looking for boundaries of `{` and `}`

Then you should use

```
Pattern.compile("(?<!\\{)" + Pattern.quote(key) + "(?!\\})").matcher(str).find()
```

rather than the `matches` with `\b` word boundaries.

The `(?<!\{)` negative lookbehind fails the match if the current position is preceded with a `{` and the `(?!\})` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a `}` right after the current position.